# How to uninstall software that doesnt show in Ubuntu Software

Tags: software-uninstall

Ubuntu 22.04
So, I installed the official Minecraft Launcher using Wine. Wine Can't uninstall it, and it doesn't show in Ubuntu software. The application has no Uninstaller for you to go to. What am I supposed to do about this?
Install method: Website - Linux build - Install (needed a few extra things that are being used for other programs.)
Wine uninstaller is not an option. Previously stated wine is unable to uninstall it.
Build: 22.04
Website software accessed from: minecraft.net
(The above website is in fact a trusted site for Mojang. This is where you can download the official minecraft Launcher for systems using a seperate OS than windows.)

Comment: What about running in terminal `wine uninstaller`?

Comment: At least tell us the build and/or install commands. If necessary point us to the website.

Answer (score 1):

As a general answer to your general question "How to uninstall software that doesnt show in Ubuntu Software", there is no general answer: how you uninstall software that you did not install using a package management system (APT, Snap, flatpak) entirely depends on the specific software. Software may or may not provide removal scripts. If not, then the only way may be to manually delete all files installed with the program and undo any configuration, provided you can get to know or guess these files or that configuration from the documentation or, in the worst case, by examining your system files yourself.